# blacklist tag modal-view-controller

Tags: discussion, tag-block-request

Even though they differ by only one letter, there's an important conceptual difference between the terms "modal view controller" and "model/view/controller". The first is a view controller presented in a certain "modal" fashion, and the second is a pattern. The [modal-view-controller](/questions/tagged/modal-view-controller) tag creates potential for confusion since it looks like "model/view/controller" but means "modal view controller". It should be replaced entirely by the [modalviewcontroller](/questions/tagged/modalviewcontroller) tag. I've editted the three existing questions that used the offending tag so that they now use [modalviewcontroller](/questions/tagged/modalviewcontroller).

I'm not sure how to start the blacklisting process for a given tag, but I'd like to see [modal-view-controller](/questions/tagged/modal-view-controller) removed from the lexicon of tags.

Comment: Words are separated by hyphens in tags, and I don't see how removing them would make the tag less susceptible to misuse.

Comment: @MatthewRead The [tag:modalviewcontroller] tag already exists and is the one that's currently used by 492 questions. Removing the currently unused [tag:modal-view-controller] tag will help avoid confusion with [tag:model-view-controller].

Comment: A mod can easily merge the hyphenless version into the hypenated version, effecting a rename.  Stating that the hyphenless version will avoid confusion, without any reasoning, isn't much of an argument.  It appears ModalViewController is part of the iOS SDK or something, so that **does** make sense as a name.  I can't agree that blacklisting "modal view controller" is helpful though, following Anna's reasoning.

Comment: @MatthewRead Sorry, I haven't explained clearly enough. Words in Obj-C are often run together and camelCased, as in `-presentModalViewController:`. So it's not a big stretch for an Obj-C developer to read 'modalviewcontroller' and associate that with the right concept. When talking about the "model view controller" pattern, however the words are always separate, so hyphens there make more sense (as does the other common way to refer to the pattern, [tag:MVC]). Creating a visual distinction between the two tags instead of relying on the subtle difference between 'a' and 'e' will help readers.

Comment: Alright, I can buy that.  Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are tag synonyms and merged tags? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think blacklisting a legitimate tag is a good idea. It's unfortunate that it's getting misused, but are you sure that nobody is using [modalviewcontroller](/questions/tagged/modalviewcontroller) wrong?

Setting up a synonym from [modal-view-controller](/questions/tagged/modal-view-controller) to [modalviewcontroller](/questions/tagged/modalviewcontroller) or the other way around would be a good idea, though, since both tags mean the same thing and there's no need to have both. IMHO, the version with hyphens is better and more readable, but if the hyphen-less version has more questions, it can be the master tag.

Comment: Anna, I can't say I've checked all the questions, but people seem to be distinguishing properly between [tag:modalviewcontroller] and [tag:mvc] (for which [tag:model-view-controller] is a synonym). I think making [tag:modal-view-controller] a synonym for [tag:modelviewcontroller] is a fine suggestion. I'm surprised to see that I don't have a high enough score in [tag:modalviewcontroller] to create that synonym, but I'd certainly support it were someone else to create it. Thanks.

Comment: @Caleb I set up the synonym.