# encouraging users to use more specific tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, questions, asking-questions

When newcomers ask questions about [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) they usually specify no more details. They hardly read the Smart Questions essay and such. However frequently their question is specific to their Delphi version. Either because they describe a version-specific bug, or because the answer should only use features present in the poster's version and such. It also may make search easier for those answering whose experience is with different versions.

I remember the FIDO forum on Delphi, where specifying the version in the header (or explicitly specifying the question being generic for all versions) was mandatory.

There are a lot of tags like [delphi-5](/questions/tagged/delphi-5) and [delphi-xe3](/questions/tagged/delphi-xe3) yet posters probably just don't care or don't know about them.

Proposal: tags like [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) can have a list of derived tags like [delphi-2006](/questions/tagged/delphi-2006) and such. Then if some new question goes with the former but with none of the latter ones, the SO engine would pop-up a confirmation dialog, asking the user to either specify his version or explicitly claim his question being generic enough to apply to any version.

I believe such a feature would be useful not only for Delphi but for all other semantically connected tags.

PS. This question had "Tags asking for tags" title initially. I still think that was a better name. If someone wants SO to ask for tags - those would be the words he would use for searching. Now this topic is again missed in search results: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=ask+tag

Comment: I think this is similar to Daniel Beck's [meta-tag:feature-request] - [A real solution to ambiguous tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125234)

Comment: @Sathya that is not quite so. While DB shows visual basic as an example, he proposes forced replacing. I think replacing is wrong, unless "implicit virtual tags" would be implemented, if ever. In my proposal there should be both tags, "Delphi" and "Delphi-7", so that searches would be successful for both terms. Ideally tags like "Delphi-7" would *imply* virtual tag "Delphi", that can be made if tags would be joined into *Categories* like wikipedia articles. But that is major engine overhaul. And removing general tag like "Delphi" or "VB" after specifying certain version would be wrong IMHO

Comment: In short: those tags are not ambiguous, those are different levels of generality/concretization. And sometimes the question can really not be limited to single version. For example a question like "which VB version should i use for tasks like ..." can not be attributed to neither of versions.

Comment: Although Daniel Beck's feature request was aimed at ambiguous tags, rather than more specific tags, the proposed mechanism seems very similar to me.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Well, they are related. Had i found his proposal, i'd perhaps just stick with it. But his proposal was named in such a "marketing" style that could only be found by random search for buzzwords. And since i never considered those tags ambiguous (his example of "dsl" is good, but it is not my itch), i could not find it. Now i am even glad it came this way, i think both his stated problem and proposal are related to mine indeed but still are different.