# How do you get ambiguous tags on Stackoverflow handled?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

Stack Overflow has a tag [sys](/questions/tagged/sys) which was probably started for the Python module named `sys`. Alternatively, it could have been started for the ASP.NET namespace `Sys`. In any event, it is being used for both, which doesn't seem right.

It is also being selected by C and C++ programmers, probably as an abbreviation for "system", and by people using the Oracle database.

Is it valid to have a tag being used for incongruous things and if not, how do you bring that to someone's attention?

Comment: I've seen tags used for related but separate things in different languages ([tag:label] for example), but I only thing that makes sense if the things that are referred are similar enough. In that case I'd split it into separate trags.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I agree. They should probably eliminate it and make  python-sys-module and asp-sys-namespace tags and whatever might satisfy the Oracle DB usage. But I don't have the reputation to do that so would have to get someone else to do it somehow.

Comment: you may be interested in this feature request: [A real solution to ambiguous tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125234/165773)

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not really valid to use same tag for different meanings.

In most cases it's possible to create new tags, adding something descriptive e.g. for socket there is [unix-socket](/questions/tagged/unix-socket) while there is also [python-sockets](/questions/tagged/python-sockets).

I'm not familiar with Pyton so not sure [sys-python](/questions/tagged/sys-python) will make much sense but if it does then high rep member on Stack Overflow can create such tag then retag all the relevant questions to have it instead of the "generic" [sys](/questions/tagged/sys).