# How can “tag antonyms” — ambiguous tags with multiple distinct meanings — best be nominated for disambiguation and/or bifurcation?

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonyms, ambiguous-tags

[icc](/questions/tagged/icc) is attached to SO questions about one of two distinct things:

- The proprietary super-optimized [Intel C/C++ Compilers](http://software.intel.com/en-us/c-compilers/), or
- Color-management theory and practice having to do with ICC profiles (named for their parent governing standards organization, the [International Color Consortium](http://www.color.org/abouticc.xalter))

I myself don't know the ICC compiler from Adam but I have plenty to offer w/r/t the ICC color-profile file format. A glance through the question list reveals a litany of posts from enthusiastic specialists, each of whom have one or another form of “ICC” expertise, but never both.

Unlike many ambiguous-tag scenarios, there is really no overlap between the two realms of inquiry in this case. I don't think there's a single value-add to the tag's role representing these two domains; at the very least, when discussing homonyms/synonyms/etc like these, one can typically wring out some forced and unfunny “ICC/ICC” joke, but I've got nothing in this case.

Even though my reputation falls short of the minimum balance one needs to make tag-wiki edits, I can still write up and submit tag-wiki copy changes for review — like many of my peers, I have taken advantage of this. I don't believe there's a way to suggest other actions, like disambiguation. If that is by design, or not, that's fine either way for me; I'm only bringing this up here to illustrate the one issue with [icc](/questions/tagged/icc).

Comment: related: [A real solution to ambiguous tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/125234/165773) - "Just like a tag can be declared a *synonym* of another tag, basically changing all references to the synonym to references to that other, canonical tag, it should be possible to make it a **disambiguation tag**..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can “tag antonyms” — ambiguous tags with multiple distinct meanings, like [icc](/questions/tagged/icc) — best be nominated for disambiguation and/or bifurcation?

By posting here on meta.  Congrats, that's what you've just done.  Mission accomplished!

There are just over 100 questions in [icc](/questions/tagged/icc).  That's low enough that we don't really need diamond mods to help, but enough that we'll want to build a bit of consensus before taking action.  The action I'm going to advocate in this answer is:

- Replace [icc](/questions/tagged/icc) with [color-profile](/questions/tagged/color-profile) on questions talking about color profiles.
- Rename [icc](/questions/tagged/icc) to [intel-c-compiler](/questions/tagged/intel-c-compiler), either by hand by editing questions, or by asking for help from a diamond mod.  A synonym wouldn't be out of the question either.